# Exposing signature of a Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

All functions typically need some inputs and may or maynot return an output. What is the best way of exposing the signature of a function definition in Python to help the user to correctly provide inputs and capture a retun appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I use pythons inspect module.

So using the Python shell

```
import inspect
inspect.getargspec(sum) # any function/method head name in place of sum should work

> ArgSpec(args=['iterable', 'start'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Chun. When calling a function can you make  editors prompt you for the parameters required ? similar to prompts when using a standard Python function.

Comment: In a few IDEs they will provide an autocomplete, pycharm, IntelliJ and vscode should be able to help here.